# awk, bin/sh 0: 1: not found

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am almost brand-new to coding and I would appreciate feedback. I am trying to make a shell script that will evaluate information in a text file and moved said text file if certain conditions are met. My code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

stock=HD

awk ' /Rank/ {
    if ( $4 == "1-Strong" ) system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/1/"'$stock'.txt") ;
    else if ( $4 == "2-Buy" ) system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/2/"'$stock'.txt") ;
    else if ( $4 == "3-Hold" ) system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/3/"'$stock'.txt") ;
    else if ( $4 == "4-Sell" ) system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/4/"'$stock'.txt") ;
    else if ( $4 == "5-Strong" ) system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/5/"'$stock'.txt")
} ' $stock.txt
```

When I try to run the script, I get this error:

```
andrew@andrew-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Stocks$ ./stockscript7.sh
/bin/sh: 1: 0: not found
```

I made sure I was in bash shell. I did use chmod to give the script permissions. Otherwise from this error message I'm lost on what to try next. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`? Maybe bash is not where you think it is. Using that form of the she-bang line is portable and applies to all *nix systems. The `#!/bin/bash` however is not. Also when you use bash from the terminal do you use `sh` or `bash`? There is a difference which one you use.

Comment: You'll find coding much easier if you write it in tiny bits and test each modification instead of writing your full script and then trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Eww. Using `system()` in this way is opening you up to serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: If `/bin/bash` didn't exist, it would produce a different error message. (It's also possible for `env` to be somewhere other than `/usr/bin/env`.) See also [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) for some drawbacks of the `#!/usr/bin/env` idiom.

Comment: `system()` uses `/bin/sh`, which the use of bash **before** calling awk doesn't change.

Comment: ...btw, if you want to know what exactly your awk script is doing that's emitting this error, I'd suggest using `strace -e execve -f ./yourscript` to get the details of what it's passing to the shells launched by `system()`. However, by far the easier answer is "don't use awk for this"; unambiguously constructing command lines is a task the shell is far better at. (As far as I know, awk doesn't *have* any call that lets you specify exact execve arguments for unambiguous subprocess invocation at all).

Comment: Here's a one liner solution `mv ${stock}.txt ~/Desktop/Stocks/$(sed -n '/Rank/s/^.*\([0-9]\)-.*$/\1/p' ${stock}.txt)/`.

Comment: Awk is a tool for manipulating text. It is NOT an environment from which to move files (or manipulate processes) - that's what a shell is for. See @CharlesDuffy's answer for one way to do it using the appropriate tools. If you edit your question to show us the contents of your input file we may be able to help you more. BTW always quote shell variables unles you have a very specific reason not to and fully understand all of the implications/caveats - use `"$stock.txt"`, not `$stock.txt`.

Comment: @alvits, need more quotes for that to not be dangerous (in a "move contents other than those intended" sense). What happens if no numbers exist in the line containing `Rank`? If you quote your expansions (excluding the parts, like `~`, that you *want* to be replaced), you're at least guaranteed that in no circumstances will one expansion string-split into multiple arguments, which contains the damage with unexpected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a translation to native bash, with none of the bugs associated with abusing awk as you were (consider what would have happened with an input file named `EVIL'$(rm -rf .)'.txt` -- as created with the command `touch $'EVIL\'$(rm -rf .)\'.txt'`):

```
#!/bin/bash

stock=HD

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = *Rank* ]] || continue
  read -r _ _ _ rank _ <<<"$line"
  case $rank in
    1-Strong) mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/1/ ;;
    2-Buy)    mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/2/ ;;
    3-Hold)   mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/3/ ;;
    4-Sell)   mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/4/ ;;
    5-Strong) mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/5/ ;;
  esac
done <"$stock.txt"
```

---

However, this doesn't make much sense as it's written: You're running one `mv` per line in the file matching `Rank` -- but you can't successfully move a single file more than once. Perhaps you just want to read the **first** line containing `Rank`, and rename the file according to the number preceding a dash in the fourth column?

```
#!/bin/bash
stock=HD
if read -r _ _ _ rating _ < <(grep -e Rank "$stock.txt") && [[ $rating ]]; then
  mv -- "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"${rating%%-*}"/
fi
```

Explanation:

- `<(...)` is replaced with a filename which, when read, returns the output of the command enclosed. Thus, `foo < <(...)` runs `foo` in the parent shell with its stdin fed from the command in the `...`. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to understand why this is necessary rather than running `grep -e Rank "$stock.txt" | read _ _ _ rating _`.
- `read _ _ _ rating _` reads the fourth word of its input stream into the variable `rating`. (First, second, third, and fifth-and-on are read into variables named `_`, which is convention for something you don't care about / want to throw away).
- `"${rating%%-*}"` throws away all contents in the variable `rating` following the first `-`, thus converting `1-Strong` to `1`, `2-Buy` to `2`, etc.

---

However, all the above doesn't explain the exact error you're receiving. To get that, let's break down your `awk` commands:

```
system("mv " "'$stock'.txt" " " ~/Desktop/Stocks/1/"'$stock'.txt") ;
```

...so, what are the strings concatenated together and passed to `system()` (and thus `/bin/sh`)?

```
system(
  "mv "
  "'$stock'.txt"
  " "
  ~/Desktop/Stocks/1/"'$stock'.txt"
) ;
```

See the problem here? That fourth piece (which you intend to have concatenated together with the rest) isn't a string in awk! Thus, when it contains `/` operations, those are treated as **numeric division** -- casting the content before it to a numeric value, and dividing by the content after it (likewise cast to integer). On some awk releases, including mine, this results in a divide-by-zero error; yours apparently differs.

(Also, `$stock` is a **literal** string, not substituted with `HD` here, but that's a separate issue)

Answer (score 2):

You are currently creating this execution tree:

```
shell { awk { system( shell ) } }
```

Don't do that, it's extremely messy and error prone. Do this instead (or something equally simple):

```
shell { awk }
```

e.g. this MAY be all you need (depending on the contents of HD.txt):

```
mv "${stock}.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"$(awk '/Rank/{ sub(/-.*/,"",$4); print $4 }' "${stock}.txt")"
```

Comment: I'd suggest quoting the `$()` expansion in which you're calling awk -- if only for paranoia -- but this is a good approach I hadn't thought of. (Of course, you want to also be sure *not* to quote the `~`, or if quoting the argument as a whole to replace it with `$HOME`)

Comment: To be honest I just threw it up there to give the OP an idea of a possibility. He probably really needs something different but we won't know for sure until we see his input file contents. I'll add the quotes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things too complicated by 1) sticking just with awk and 2) repeating the file name in the destination path of those `mv` comands.

I will assume the "Rank" line has columns separated by spaces and that the 4th one is the one containing your id, as you yourself are assuming. *If either this or the following assumption do not hold, the solution here may give you problems*. See Charle's answer.

If you are sure the 4th field **always** contains a string with the pattern `digits-text` then you can try with

```
#!/bin/bash

stock=HD

id=`cat "$stock.txt"|grep Rank| cut -d ' ' -f 4| sed 's@-.*@@g'`
echo "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"$id"
#mv "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"$id"
```

I have commented out the actual `mv` command. The echo line will allow you to double check that the file would indeed go to the right destination. Make a few tests and if things look ok, uncomment the `mv` line by removing the  sign `#`.

EDIT: **Do make sure** that all the directories ~/Desktop/Stocks/$id exist **before issuing the `mv` commands**. Otherwise **you'll lose those files!**, as they would overwrite each other and only the content of the last file moved to any given ~/Desktop/Stocks/$id directory would survive -but named $id!!

The following code will make sure that they are moved into a directory and are not overwritten onto each other.

```
#!/bin/bash

stock=HD
DDIR=~/Desktop/Stocks

id=`cat "$stock.txt"|grep Rank| cut -d ' ' -f 4| sed 's@-.*@@g'`
echo "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"$id"
{ [ -d "$DDIR/$id" ] || mkdir "$DDIR/$id" ;} &&  mv "$stock.txt" ~/Desktop/Stocks/"$id"
```

This checks first for folder $DDIR/$id to exist and makes it if it doesn't. Only then proceeds with the actual move.

Comment: Also badly buggy due to missing quotes. What if the stock being processed has whitespace or glob characters in its name, or (for some reason) the `id` field had the same?

Comment: BTW, putting a final `/` after the `$id` ensures that it's a directory used as destination, and avoids the file-overwriting case you're worried about. Though you *do* still need more quotes to ensure that `mv` is passed only the number of arguments you expect.

Comment: @Jens True, but irrelevant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Again, true. However, 1) this code is a consequent of an if clause where the antecedent states that the **4th field** must be the right one; I stated that clearly. And 2) I didn't intent it to be a full proof solution. For that he/she should have provided more information as to what the content of $stocks.txt is like, which (s)he didn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Apropos ```/```: that's a good point. However, without making sure there is such a directory, just add ```/``` would make the ```mv``` exit with an error if it doesn't exist. What I wrote handles such a situation gracefully.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You have given a much more thorough answer addressing a general scenario. It's good. It might be as well a bit overwhelming for the user that asked the question, as (s)he clearly states that he's ```brand new to coding```. I addressed that point of his/her, namely, a short answer driving her/him away from that awk mess. The particular intricacies of his/her case is left to her/him.

Comment: Then read your own words: *You are making things too complicated*. A useless cat, a useless fork, a useless pipe, useless waste of CPU cycles, useless extra typing. Perfection is reached when there is nothing more to take away.

Comment: @Jens *Perfection*!? Ah, come on! Please, estimate for us the waste of CPU in such a two-liner script and explain why we should worry about it in this case.

Comment: We should worry because we want to teach best practices. A UUOC is worst practice. Students are mislead to believe that to feed data on stdin they have to pipe it using `cat`. We also shouldn't have this discussion. When a UUOC is pointed out, the correct response is "Thanks for pointing it out, I have eliminated it." Defending it is saying *I'm sloppy and I don't care*. That's simply unprofessional.

Comment: You are taking things out of proportion here. 1) My first answer to you started with *True*. So, I did acknowledge what you are saying. 2) Calling UUOC on a two liner is discussing the sex of the angels; I'm addressing a very concrete case. 3) I doubt calling me *sloppy* or  *unprofessional* is very professional. I'd say more professional would have been explaining why a comment like ```useless use...`` as @CharlesDuffy did with all of his, instead of just throwing it like that. It would have led to a more meaningful exchange for @Luteser to profit from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added a comment to my solution addressing some of your concerns. In retrospective, I could have considered a slightly more general name for stocks instead of just going with the value given by Luteser. In such a case quoting it is the way to go, you are right.

Comment: @MASL, the quoting's still not quite right. Do you mind if I edit to correct it?

Comment: Done. BTW, `{ [ -d "$DDIR/$id" ] || mkdir "$DDIR/$id" ;}` can be replaced with `mkdir -p "$DDIR/$id"`; which has the same relevant behavior (exiting with status 0 if the directory already exists; exiting with a nonzero status if content exists or is not a directory or if nothing is present in the location and no directory can be created).

Comment: That's a very good point. One question regarding the quoting of id. Given my assumptions on the Rank line and the 4th field, could you provide an example that could give problems if not quoting *$id*?   Thanks.

Comment: @MASL, simple: You're assuming the default `IFS` value. Unless you explicitly set it yourself, you don't know if that's true; consider, for instance, `IFS=1`; then, any `1` would be treated as a character to use in string-splitting an unquoted expansion, so `213` would put `2` and `3` into different words, thus separate arguments to `mv`. (Granted, anyone who exported a non-default IFS value through the environment would be Doing Things Wrong, but there are, sadly, quite a lot of folks writing scripts that think that `export` is a mandatory part of setting any shell variable's value).

Comment: @MASL, ...that said, even with the default IFS, consider `1$'\t'2-`.; the pipeline splitting only on spaces means it won't split out tabs. (To be clear, that's bash syntax for a tab literal; I don't mean the `$`, `'`, etc. to be taken as literals themselves).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88799/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-masl).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, *I did assume Luteser knew what his file contains*. (S)he showed enough familiarity with awk to be sensible for me assuming that. Yet, your answer leaves me thinking on what's the best audience I should address my answers to. Thanks.

Comment: It's one thing to know what one's file *should* contain, another to know what it *will* contain when deployed to production in the presence of bugs, attacks, unexpected 3rd-party code changes, and the like. See in particular the formulation of Postel's Law in section 1.2.2 of RFC 1122: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#page-12

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I saw your invitation to the chat after my last comment. I answered you there.

Comment: @Luteser it would be good if you'd accept one of the answers in case any does satisfy you. Thanks.